# R - how to get the end date of the week and month from a given date?

Tags: r, date, datetime, lubridate

How, in R, to get end dates of week, fortnight(beginning date too), month, quarter and year.

Let's say, we have date is "July 15th, 2017" and below code gets beginning dates.

```
> (a_date <- as.Date("15-07-17", "%d-%m-%y"))
[1] "2017-07-15"
> (beginning_date_week <- as.Date(cut(a_date, "week")))
[1] "2017-07-10"
> (beginning_date_month <- as.Date(cut(a_date, "month")))
[1] "2017-07-01"
> (beginning_date_quarter <- as.Date(cut(a_date, "quarter")))
[1] "2017-07-01"
> (beginning_date_year <- as.Date(cut(a_date, "year")))
[1] "2017-01-01"
```

adding 7 days to beginning date of week may get me the end date of week.

But, for month addition is simply not elegant(since some months have 30 days, some 31, some 28(29 some times)) and it only gets worse for quarters and years.

Answer (score 3):

`ceiling_date` in the `lubridate` package returns the first date of the following period. Subtract 1 to get the last date of the current period.

```
library(lubridate)

a_date <- as.Date("15-07-17", "%d-%m-%y")

ceiling_date(a_date, "week", week_start = getOption("lubridate.week.start", 1))-1
[1] "2017-07-16"

ceiling_date(a_date, "month")-1
[1] "2017-07-31"

ceiling_date(a_date, "quarter")-1
[1] "2017-09-30"

ceiling_date(a_date, "year")-1
[1] "2017-12-31"
```